# C3.js create a chart by getting the data from external API

Tags: c3.js

I am trying to create a chart in c3.js and my data is coming from an external API. I want to get the data and the keys from the json data so that I can plot the values on the chart. I have added the external api format and the js code below.

**JSON DATA:**

```
[{ 
      "label" : "A Label" ,
      "value" : -29.765957771107
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "B Label" , 
      "value" : 0
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "C Label" , 
      "value" : 32.807804682612
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "D Label" , 
      "value" : 196.45946739256
    }]
```

**JS Code:**

```
d3.json("http://localhost:8080/api/study", function(data) {
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto : '#chartContainer',
        data : {
            columns : ['label']
        },
         keys: {
            x: 'label',
            value: ['value']
        }
    });
});
```

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Pre-process the API data into the format that C3 requires. It should be straightforward:

```
var convertedData = [];
apiData.forEach(function(item){
    convertedData.push([item.label, item.value]);
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/2/

EDIT:
If you're wanting to use the JSON data option with the value array, then it would be something like this, where you set the json property, and the keys object:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: data,
        keys: {
            x: 'label',
            value: ["value"]
        },
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show:false
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/4/

Comment: Thank You, for the code now the charts are working fine. This is helpful.

Comment: It's a pleasure. If it's the right answer, please mark it as such. Thanks.